# Unable to Create Azure Storage Queue Messages with ASP.NET 4.6.1 App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage-queues

I have an old ASP.NET 4.6.1 app running in a VM on Azure.

I’m trying to create messages in an Azure Storage Queue and nothing is happening when I run it on production VM. However, on my dev machine, it works fine and I can create messages in the same queue that I’m trying to access from the production VM.

The call to the queue is within a `try catch` block and it’s not throwing any errors.

Another important point is that I had use the old/deprecated `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet package as that’s the one that seems to work on this ASP.NET MVC 4.6.1 app.

Any idea what could be the issue here? Because I don’t see any errors, I’m not sure how to go about fixing this problem.

Comment: it would be useful to provide more info, like code or logs

Comment: There are something you need to check: 1.are you using the correct connection string for that azure storage? 2.are you checking the queue messages in the correct queue storage? 3. are there any azure functions which are consuming the queue? 4.if possible, can you use some tools like `fiddler` in your production VM, and check what happens when the related code is running.

Comment: @Sam What mechanism are you using to access the storage queue? If you are using SAS, please, double check if you are filtering by IP address or applying any other restriction when controlling the access to the queue. Possibly the SDK should report an error indicating unauthorized access, but perhaps that error is being masked in the code. Also, verify if firewall access to the storage account is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MS Docs, one troubleshooting option you can try is **"Redeploy Windows virtual machine to new Azure node"**

The doc says,

> If you have been facing difficulties troubleshooting Remote Desktop
> (RDP) connection or **application access to Windows-based Azure virtual
> machine (VM)**, redeploying the VM may help.

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/redeploy-to-new-node-windows

See also **additional troubleshooting steps:**

1. Restart the virtual machine
2. Recreate the endpoint / firewall rules / network security group
   (NSG) rules
3. Connect from different location, such as a different Azure virtual
   network
4. Recreate the virtual machine

> There are various reasons when you cannot start or connect to an application running on an Azure virtual machine (VM). Reasons include the application not running or listening on the expected ports, the listening port blocked, or networking rules not correctly passing traffic to the application.

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-app-connection

Answer (score 0):

This might be network Firewall issue. Open azure portal from production vm machine. You can even try to manually see the storage and upload files from web.